# Docker ee ucp issue - encountered below error after reboot of node and ucp controller shows unhealthy status

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-ucp

Error : unable to authenticate user with refresh token on auth provider: invalid_grant : no such account for refresh token

Answer (score 0):

If this is the problem I'm thinking of, that error is just a red herring.

In some versions of UCP, when you reboot a manager node, something funky happens with the ucp-auth image, and it loses its tag. Because the image is messed up, the `ucp-auth-worker` and `ucp-auth-api` containers cannot start. This in turn, causes the `ucp-controller` to stay in the unhealthy state.

You can check this with `docker images`

Look for the ucp-auth image, and check out the tag. If the tag reads `<none>` then this is your issue. Typically, all you have to do to fix this, is do a `docker pull docker/ucp-auth:<your ucp version>` then restart the docker engine.